# Ping 'Realm local all Thread nodes' multicast

Tags: raspbian, ping, ipv6

I'm using rpi3 with raspbian to set up an OpenThread Borderrouter.

For my application, I need to ping the 'Realm local all thread nodes' multicast address. Unfortunately, I get an error when doing that.

RPi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ip a     
4: wpan0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet6 fd11:22:db8:2:344a:548f:f779:1042/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdde:ad11:11de:0:54a2:27d7:912d:fa3f/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::344a:548f:f779:1042/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::be6c:eeb:861a:bc23/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Node IP:

```
Interface 0: 6LoWPAN
    Link local address (LL64): fe80::7871:37b3:26e5:9674
    Mesh local address (ML64): fdde:ad11:11de::7837:c901:e10b:1785
    Mesh local address (ML16): fdde:ad11:11de::ff:fe00:0
    Unique local address: fd11:22:db8:2:8454:4a6f:2eb2:ee50
    Link local all Thread Nodes(MCast):  ff32:40:fdde:ad11:11de::1
    Realm local all Thread Nodes(MCast): ff33:40:fdde:ad11:11de::1
```

RPi:

Pinging the link local multicast works:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping6 ff32:40:fdde:ad11:11de::1%wpan0
PING ff32:40:fdde:ad11:11de::1%wpan0 (ff32:40:fdde:ad11:11de::1%wpan0): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::344a:548f:f779:1042%wpan0: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
64 bytes from fe80::7871:37b3:26e5:9674%wpan0: icmp_seq=0 ttl=1 time=245.916 ms (DUP!)
```

But pinging the realm local multicast does not:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/coap $ ping6 ff33:40:fdde:ad11:11de::1%wpan0
ping6: unknown host ff33:40:fdde:ad11:11de::1%wpan0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inetutils-ping` has minimal implementation of ping6 which does not include the '-I (interface)' command-line argument.
Pinging any non-link-local IPv6 multicast address does not see to work (results in a 'unknown host'-error), even when using the '%(interface)' notation.

To ping realm local multicast addresses I had to install iputils-ping:

> sudo apt-get install -y iputils-ping

After which I was able to use the -I interface-option which allowed me to ping the address.